# Pointers, Arrays and Functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I programmed a function which can rotate 4 x 4 arrays, and now i want to output it... But I get a bunch warnings, but it compiles and works, so I guess i only did some "minor/formal" mistakes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
///
/// This function prints four 4x4 matrix
///
/// @param m1, m2, m3, m4 input matrix you want to print.
///
/// @return 0
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void *print_matrix(char m1[4][4], char m2[4][4], char m3[4][4], char m4[4][4])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("%c ", m1[i][j]);
            }
            printf(" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("%c ", m2[i][j]);
            }
            printf(" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("%c ", m3[i][j]);
            }
            printf(" ");
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("%c ", m4[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
///
/// This function rotates a 4x4 matrix 
/// (and collects tears from overworked students @2am, because wtf is  )
///
/// @param m, the matrix you want to rotate
///
/// @return m_r the rotated matrix
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

char *rotate_matrix(char m[4][4])
{
    static char m_r[4][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            m_r[i][j] = m[3-j][i];
        }
    }
    return *m_r;
}

int main(void)
{
char matrix_t [4][4] = {{ '-', '-', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', 'O', '-', '-' },
                        { 'O', 'O', 'O', '-' },
                        { '-', '-', '-', '-' }
                       };
char matrix_z [4][4] = {{   '-', '-', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', 'O', 'O', '-' },
                        { 'O', 'O', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', '-', '-', '-' }
                       };
char matrix_l [4][4] = {{   '-', '-', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', 'O', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', 'O', '-', '-' },
                        { '-', 'O', 'O', '-' }
                       };
char matrix_i [4][4] = {{   '-', '-', 'O', '-' },
                        { '-', '-', 'O', '-' },
                        { '-', '-', 'O', '-' },
                        { '-', '-', 'O', '-' }
                       };
char (*array)[4][4];

  print_matrix(matrix_t, matrix_z, matrix_l, matrix_i);
  array = rotate_matrix(matrix_t);
  print_matrix(array, matrix_z, matrix_l, matrix_i);
    return 0;
}
```

This are the errors i get:

```
102:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]


array = rotate_matrix(matrix_t);
```

,

```
103:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_matrix’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]


print_matrix(array, matrix_z, matrix_l, matrix_i);
```

and

```
note: expected ‘char (*)[4]’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[4][4]’


void *print_matrix(char m1[4][4], char m2[4][4], char m3[4][4], char m4[4][4])
```

And to be honest, i don't get these errors, because the code seems to work, I'm never out of boundaries and obviously I'm not doing any memory violations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are because these:

```
char *            // pointer to char         or to first element of char[]
char (*)[4]       // pointer to char[4]      or to first element of char[][4]
char (*)[4][4]    // pointer to char[4][4]   or to first element of char[][4][4]
```

are different types. A pointer doesn't just denote a memory location, but also (via its type) how that memory location should be interpreted.

One tricky bit is that an array name (or any other expression that evaluates to an array) *decays* to a pointer. For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
char abc[4] = "abc";    // abc is an array of four characters
char a = *abc;          // a is 'a', the first character of abc
```

. . . and conversely, you can use array notation on a pointer (to perform pointer arithmetic and immediately dereference the result):

```
char * abc = "abc";     // abc is a pointer (into static memory)
char c = abc[2];        // c is 'c', the third character of abc
```

So `char *` is interconvertible with `char ()[]`, `char (*)[4]` is interconvertible with `char ()[][4]`, and `char (*)[4][4]` is interconvertible with `char ()[][4][4]`.

And what makes it *extra* tricky is that C doesn't quite support passing an array as a function parameter (though if you really want that, you can achieve the same effect by wrapping the array in a struct and passing that). It does let you declare a function parameter as having an array type, but that is actually syntactic sugar for a function parameter with a *pointer* type. So these three signatures are equivalent:

```
void *print_matrix(char m1[4][4], char m2[4][4], char m3[4][4], char m4[4][4])
void *print_matrix(char m1[][4], char m2[][4], char m3[][4], char m4[][4])
void *print_matrix(char (*m1)[4], char (*m2)[4], char (*m3)[4], char (*m4)[4])
```

Your code works because your various warnings all sort of cancel out:

- `rotate_matrix` *should* return either a `char (*)[4]` (a pointer to the first row of a `char[][4]`) or a `char (*)[4][4]` (a pointer to a complete `char[4][4]`). Instead, you have it return `char *`, and to accomplish that, you dereference the desired pointer, thereby getting (after array-to-pointer decay) a pointer to the first element of the first row of the matrix. Of course, all of these pointers point to the same memory location, just with different types.

  - To declare it with return-type `char (*)[4]`, you can write `char (*rotate_matrix(char m[4][4]))[4]` . . . but it's probably better to declare a `row` type, `typedef char row[4]`, and then write `row * rotate_matrix(char m[4][4])`. In this case you would return `m_r` at the end, which decays to a pointer to the first row of `m_r`.
  - To declare it with return-type `char (*)[4][4]`, same thing, just with extra `[4]`'s (and a name like `matrix` rather than `row`). In this case you would return `&m_r` at the end, meaning a pointer to the entirety of `m_r`.
  - Either of the above approaches is fine IMHO, though of course you'll have to adjust the calling sites to match. For the rest of this answer, I'm going to assume we're doing the second version, the one with return-type `char (*)[4][4]`.
- `array` has type `char (*)[4][4]`, which is fine. The code warning in `array = rotate_matrix(matrix_t)` is because of the mis-declaration of `rotate_matrix`. But the actual value of the returned pointer was already fine, at least on typical platforms.

  - That said, if you're going to use this type for `array`, then you should probably call it `array_ptr`, since it's a *pointer* to your usual array type.
- But then you pass `array` as an argument to `print_matrix`, which takes a parameter of type `char [4][4]`, meaning `char (*)[4]`. You can't convert a `char (*)[4][4]` (pointer to array of 4 rows of 4 chars) to a `char (*)[4]` (pointer to array of 4 chars). To fix this, you just need to dereference `array`, by passing `*array` instead.

(Note: I'm not sure that all of the above implicit conversions are actually *guaranteed* to work; pointers to different types of objects might not all be interconvertible on all platforms. And even on typical modern platforms, where they *are* all interconvertible, you might run afoul of strict aliasing rules, which means that your compiler might end up performing optimizations that totally break your code. But it will *usually* work.)

Comment: Thanks! But I've never used a 1 dimensional Array in my code... Is there any formal mistake in describing the 2 dimensional arrays that makes c think I've used a 1 dimensional one? Because that drives me insane...

Comment: @ManuelBurgstaller: Yes; sorry, I alluded to it in my last paragraph, but I didn't make a big point of it because I forgot that it actually *was* relevant to your program. (I was thinking of it as a "by the way".) I'll edit my answer to be more clear about it.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll try to wrap my head around it after I've got some sleep (not going to go to bed 5 hours late like yesterday xD)